# How can I add a link inside smarty array

Tags: php, smarty3

Hi wonder if you can help

I have an image gallery which uses a fancybox pop up. Each image has a caption, the caption is a plain text containing a web address example: www.mywebsite.com

I want to make the caption a link which goes to the address stated in the caption text.
it's inside a smarty array, how can I add a a simple href to the outputted 'caption' inside here?

```
$smarty->assign(array(

  'gallery_title' => 
      (($id_gallery > 0 AND isset($images[$id_gallery])) 
         AND isset($images[$id_gallery]['caption'])
         AND isset($images[$id_gallery]['caption'][(int)($cookie->id_lang)]))
            ? $images[$id_gallery]['caption'][(int)($cookie->id_lang)] 
            : NULL,
  'title'=> (int)(Configuration::get('IMAGE_GALL_NC_TITLE')),
```

I'm not a coder, so I'm unsure of the syntax inside a smarty array. can anyone help me add the link sort of like **a href="http://{$caption}"**  in the right place

Thanks very much for time
sarah

Answer (score 0):

This is an basic example how you can pass and array variable to smarty:

Php Code:

```
    $myarray_php = array("link" => "http://www.website.com");
    $smarty->assign('myarray', $myarray_php);
```

Smarty Code:

```
{section name=myarray_loop loop=$myarray}
<a href='{$myarray[myarray_loop].link'>Click Here</a>
{/section}
```